# Pip install with requirements.txt from private repo prompting for password

Tags: python, github, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to install a python package `my_package` from a private Github repo using `pip`. I am using Github oauth tokens (aka personal access tokens) for security. My token is stored in the environment variable `$API_TOKEN`.

From the console if I do:
`pip install git+https://${API_TOKEN}@github.com/johnf1004/my_package.git` then it works perfectly.

According to the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#using-environment-variables), you should be able to use environment variables inside `requirements.txt`. However if I do `pip install -r requirements.txt` where the file has the exact same address as above (`git+https://${API_TOKEN}@github.com/johnf1004/my_package.git`) then it fails with a password prompt. FWIW, even a correct password for my Github account still results in failure.

Am I formatting the address/env variable wrong in the requirements file, or what am I missing?

Comment: As the docs [mentions](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html#github) you also need to specify your github username

Comment: Unfortunately this results in `Authentication failed`. The section "From a Git repository" in the documents you linked would indicate that my method should work fine :(

Answer (score 2):

Rather than encoding your credentials (either directly or via an environment variable) into your `requirements.txt` file, you should configure a [credentials helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) for git.

Leave the bare URL in your `requirements.txt` file:

```
git+https://github.com/johnf1004/my_package.git
```

Configure an appropriate credentials helper, such as the [`gh` cli](https://cli.github.com/). In recent versions, you can run `gh auth setup-git` to create the necessary configuration.

Run `gh auth login` to authenticate to GitHub:

```
$ gh auth login
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? SSH
? Upload your SSH public key to your GitHub account? Skip
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser

! First copy your one-time code: ABCD-1234
Press Enter to open github.com in your browser...
Opening in existing browser session.
✓ Authentication complete.
- gh config set -h github.com git_protocol ssh
✓ Configured git protocol
✓ Logged in as larsks
```

Now `git` will get credentials for `https://github.com` URLs from `gh` without requiring any interaction on your part.

Comment: Interesting! Your output above makes it seem like there are going to be prompts that require human input, is that right? I actually need it not to have prompts as I'm eventually going to be deploying my app via docker. Aware there's probably a workaround but I'd rather not go down that road when my method in theory should work...

Comment: "there are going to be prompts that require human input, is that right?" No, that's only required once in order to authenticate. Once you've done that, `git clone` will operate non-interactively. Try setting it up and see how it works.

Comment: @larsks but that does not work for the cases when you cannot prompts at all, e.g. for GH actions

Comment: @old-ufo Sure, but that wasn't a requirement in the original question. We can only answer the questions people *actually* ask.